# Is there any way to trigger run a google colab script or google cloud shell script from google apps script?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

looking to trigger run a python script when a cell updates on my google sheet. Need it to be in the cloud so it can run 24/7 Thanks!

I was thinking about triggering it via api which could be called in google apps script. not that good at coding....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.